# Delete files in offline docker container

Tags: docker, lucene, zanata

I am working with the following docker files: https://github.com/zanata/zanata-docker-files

After I ran the `./zanata-server/runapp.sh`, It started two docker containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
654580794e7c        zanata/server:latest   "/opt/jboss/wildfl..."   18 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   zanata
311f3379635e        mariadb:10.1           "docker-entrypoint..."   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          3306/tcp                 zanatadb
```

After a blackout, the zanata server container broke, it left some Lock files around and I cannot start it again:

```
org.zanata.exception.ZanataInitializationException: Lucene lock files found. Check if Zanata is already running. Otherwise, Zanata was not shut down cleanly: delete the lock files: [/var/lib/zanata/indexes/org.zanata.model.
HTextFlowTarget/write.lock, /var/lib/zanata/indexes/org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration/write.lock, /var/lib/zanata/indexes/org.zanata.model.HProject/write.lock]
```

How can I delete the lock files?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I thought I need to delete the files while the container is offline, but indeed I needed to run the container, after I could connect to it and run commands on like I was on a normal server.

The main solution:

```
sudo docker exec -it 654580794e7c bash
```

This allows me to execute commands on the container:

```
[jboss@654580794e7c ~]$ ls
wildfly
```

The whole process, if you would like to see:

```
zanata@zanata:~/docker/zanata-docker-files-platform-4.1.1/zanata-server$ sudo docker ps
[sudo] password for zanata:
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
654580794e7c        zanata/server:latest   "/opt/jboss/wildfl..."   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   zanata
311f3379635e        mariadb:10.1           "docker-entrypoint..."   2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          3306/tcp                 zanatadb
zanata@zanata:~/docker/zanata-docker-files-platform-4.1.1/zanata-server$ sudo docker exec -it 654580794e7c bash
[jboss@654580794e7c ~]$ ls
wildfly
[jboss@654580794e7c ~]$ cd /var/lib
[jboss@654580794e7c lib]$ ls
alternatives  games      machines  rpm        systemd  zanata
dbus          initramfs  misc      rpm-state  yum
[jboss@654580794e7c lib]$ cd zanata/indexes
[jboss@654580794e7c indexes]$ ls -lh
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:14 org.zanata.model.HAccount
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:14 org.zanata.model.HGlossaryEntry
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:14 org.zanata.model.HGlossaryTerm
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:30 org.zanata.model.HProject
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:30 org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  3 07:23 org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget
drwxr-xr-x 2 jboss jboss 4.0K Mar  2 13:14 org.zanata.model.tm.TransMemoryUnit
[jboss@654580794e7c indexes]$ cd org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget/
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget]$ ls
_0.cfe  _0.cfs  _0.si  segments_2  write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget]$ rm write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget]$ ls
_0.cfe  _0.cfs  _0.si  segments_2
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget]$ cd .
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HTextFlowTarget]$ cd ..
[jboss@654580794e7c indexes]$ cd org.zanata.model.HProject
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProject]$ ls
_0.cfe  _0.cfs  _0.si  segments_2  write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProject]$ rm write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProject]$ cd ..
[jboss@654580794e7c indexes]$ cd org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration/
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration]$ ls
_0.cfe  _0.cfs  _0.si  segments_2  write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration]$ rm write.lock
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration]$ ^C
[jboss@654580794e7c org.zanata.model.HProjectIteration]$ exit
zanata@zanata:~/docker/zanata-docker-files-platform-4.1.1/zanata-server$
```